# Int array to WriteableBitmap in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How to convert array of pixels int[] to WriteableBitmap in Windows Phone 8? Later on I'd like to save this image to MediaLibrary.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I am trying since yesterday... Ok I can create WriteableBitmap, but later I can't save it using MediaLibrary, I get `System.InvalidOperationException`, I was told it is because of incorrectly created WriteableBitmap.

Comment: What have you tried? Show exactly what you're doing. How are you trying to save it? What operation causes the exception?  To get good answers you need to write good questions. See  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know on Windows Phone is using the WriteableBitmapEx library. In addition to WriteableBitmap it implements an "SetPixel method with various overloads":

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

The Library can simply be installed from within Visual Studio 2012:

PROJECT => Manage NuGet Packages => Online => Search for "WriteableBitmapEx"

Answer (score 0):

You may use copyTo member function of int[] for copying int[] to WriteableBitmap.

```
int[] ARGBPx = new int[(int)captureDevice.PreviewResolution.Width * (int)captureDevice.PreviewResolution.Height];            
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap_preview;        

ARGBPx.CopyTo(writeableBitmap_preview.Pixels, 0);         
writeableBitmap_preview.Invalidate();
```